# Redirect / URL to /homepage/index/en one using RewriteEngine

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a .hraccess that displays homepage and language in "/homepage/index/en" style.
I want to Redirect (Using 301 code) requests to "site.com" to "site.com/homepage/index/en" using RewriteEngine.
I tried this:

```
RewriteRule   ^/$  /homepage/index/en  [R]
```

But this doesn't work!
How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was other RewriteRules !I added [L] flag and problem solved:

```
RewriteRule   ^/$  /homepage/index/en  [R,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try these one of these should work:

```
RewriteRule   ^/?$  /homepage/index/en  [R=301]
```

OR

```
RewriteRule   ^/?$  homepage/index/en  [R=301]
```

OR (the following one also works if there is a query string like `site.com/?a=46&b=47`

```
RewriteRule   ^/?(\?.*)?$  homepage/index/en  [R=301]
```

And If you want any query string following the `site.com/` to be appended you can use the `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule   ^/?(\?.*)?$  homepage/index/en  [R=301,QSA]
```

By the way questions pertaining to server configuration are more suited for ServerFault.com